# Acionar um botão collapse através do menu

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap, nav-bar, collapse

Na página que estou desenvolvendo, os conteúdos estão todos escondidos pela classe "collapse" do bootstrap. Como é uma Single Page, gostaria que o meu menu fosse até sua respctiva section e então mostrasse o conteúdo sem precisar clicar no botão.

Vou colocar um exemplo aqui:

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#item1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
<div class="container">
  <section id="item1">
    <a href="conteudo-item1" data-toggle="collapse">Saiba Mais</a>
    <div id="conteudo-item1" class="container collapse">
      Conteúdo...
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Estou tentando fazer isso usando o jQuery, mas não estou conseguindo.
Já utilizei os eventos click(), triggle() e triggleHandler().

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza se entendi direito a pergunta, mas vou tentar responder.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('conteudo-item1').each(function () {
        var offset = $(this).parent().offset().top;
        if (scroll > offset) {
            $(this).collapse('show');
        } else {
            $(this).collapse('hide');
        }
    });
});
```